# @supports doesn't compile from Sass to CSS

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs

I have written some Sass code. I use Visual Studio Code, and all the automation is done with Grunt (for pre-processing I use grunt-contrib-sass).

Here is my code:

```scss
.news {
  background-color: #f8f5f2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5ddd5;

  @supports (clip-path: polygon(0 0)) or (-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0)) {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 34px, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 34px, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    margin-top: -35px;
  }
}
```

There is no `@supports` directive in the CSS after compilation. I also tried to do it in LESS and with other code editors.

What's the problem?

Comment: Could you check by placing the `@supports` rule outside the `.news` ruleset (be sure to wrap the properties inside a new `.news { … }`)? I know SASS should compile this but it might help figure your issue out.

Comment: i tried so. Nothing changed)

Comment: It is pertinent to know that it's not SASS that's stripping out the @supports, but rather THIS plugin: **gulp-merge-media-queries**. At least for me, once I removed this, my `@supports` started compiling correctly. Check in your gulpfile.js if you're using it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code compiles for me, so there's nothing wrong with it, as such. I suspect you're using an old version of Sass, in which case `@supports` will not compile correctly. See this GitHub issue, fixed in 2014: https://github.com/sass/libsass/pull/612